# Custom Option, File Upload Name

Tags: custom-options, file-upload

**Custom Option - File Upload:**

When uploading a file on a Custom Option of a Product it ends up at:

\media\custom_options\quote*

When you upload a file.jpg, it ends up being renamed into 123kjhkjhkjhdsk.jpg.

**What I need:**

I need it to be saved in Original Name.

**What I have done so far:**

Now, I was able to modify \lib\Varien\File\Uploader.php 
https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php#L532

```
static public function getDispretionPath($fileName)
{
    $dispretionPath = '/orders';

    return $dispretionPath;
}
```

to store the files into a different folder.

But I cant find anywhere where the filename is being changed.

Any ideas?

PS: reason for Original Filename is because files uploaded need to be avaliable for download through FTP. So having original name and order # as a folder will solve current requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I want to say that you shouldn't use the real name of the file. What if 2 customers upload a file with the same name? The first one will get overwritten.
I suggest you use something like `original_file_name_SomeHashHERe.png`.
Also don't change the `getDispretionPath` method from the uploader class.
For 2 reasons: 1. You should never edit the core code. 2. That method is used by multple actions. If you change it it will be changed for all the other actions. You don't want that.

Now a possible solution. 
The file name is changed in the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File::_validateUploadedFile`.
More specific on this line:

```
$fileHash = md5(file_get_contents($fileInfo['tmp_name']));
```

Override the method and change that line.
Also the same method can solve you your dispersion path problem.
The line above the one that changes the file name is

```
$filePath = $dispersion;
```

Change `$dispersion` to what ever you need.

Comment: Thanks!!! SOLVED! I went over that file before but did not find the hashing line before.

Reason for original file name is: all orders will be separated by Order# and Customer Name and also the way these files are going to be uploaded only by the admin. 

The front-end uploading is already done by another plugin that handles customer uploads to another folder.